# .htaccess перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess

Почему-то когда заходишь по ссылке site.ru/captcha, то перенаправляет на site.ru/modules/captcha, а когда заходишь по ссылке site.ru/captcha/, то всё как нужно, никуда не перенаправляет.

```
RewriteRule ^captcha/?$ modules/captcha/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^captcha/(.*?)/?$ modules/captcha/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: перед слэшем вставь символ |, тобишь так
RewriteRule ^captcha|/?$ modules/captcha/index.php [L,QSA]

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, слэш вообще заменил весь сайт мне на капчу. Вот содержимое htaccess http://pastebin.com/Kbj30Emq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обоих случаях срабатывает первое правило.

http://site.ru/captcha -> modules/captcha/index.php

http://site.ru/captcha/ -> modules/captcha/index.php

И что значит "все как нужно, никуда не перенаправляет" - а открывается что при этом?

Скорее всего у вас срабатывает другие правила из .htaccess которые вы сюда не скопировали. Покажите его целиком.

Comment: >> все как нужно, никуда не перенаправляет

Имел ввиду, что открывается http://site.ru/captcha/, как и нужно. А если не указать слэш на конце, то перебрасывает на /modules/captcha